# Keeping popup text open after marker refresh in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, popup, events

I have written a JavaScript code (I just got started) which queries the [Opensky](https://opensky-network.org/) [REST API](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html) every 10 seconds. After I collect the data, I plot it through Leaflet.js. For each item I add a popup text box which opens when I click on the tooltip.
So far the code works great!

Here is the code so you can play around:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="id=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
            crossorigin="">
        </script>
        <style>
            #openskyMap { 
                height: 800px; 
                width:1200px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>
            "FETCH JSON from API and map lat lon"
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Where are the flights</h1>
        <p>Last Update (UNIX time): <span id="ts"></span></p>

        <div id="openskyMap"></div>

        /*                           JAVASCRIPT CODE BEGINS HERE                             */ 
        <script>

            /* DEFINE OPENSKY API URL */
            var opensky_url = "https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?time=TIME";

            /* INITIATE LEAFLET MAP */
            const mymap = L.map('openskyMap').setView([45, 0], 3);
            const attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreatMap</a> contributors'
            const tileUrl = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
            const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution});
            var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);
            tiles.addTo(mymap);

            /* CHANGE ICON SIZE BASED ON ZOOM */
            mymap.on('zoomend', function(e) {
                var currentZoom = mymap.getZoom();
                console.log("Current Zoom" + " " + currentZoom);
                if (currentZoom >= 10) {
                damsRadius = 100;
                } else {
                damsRadius = 20000;
                }
            });

            /* FUNCTION TO GET THE ICAO24 CODE. I CANNOT GET IT OUT OF HERE THOUGH! */
            function getIcao24(e) {
                var popup = e.target.getPopup();
                var content = popup.getContent();
                console.log(content)
                return content
            }

            /* INITIATE QUERY FUNCTION */
            async function getOpensky() {

                /* CALCULATE UNIX TIME TO BE PASSED TO THE URL */
                var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
                ts = ts.toString();

                /* MAKE QUERY TO OPENSKY URL */
                const  response = await fetch(opensky_url.replace('TIME',ts));
                const data = await response.json();

                /* PLOT ITEMS TO MAP USING LEAFLET:js */
                layerGroup.clearLayers();
                for (var key in data.states) {

                    /* GET SINGLE ITEM FROM JSON */
                    const item = data.states[key];

                    try{ 

                       /* GET GEOGRAPHICAL COORDINATES*/
                        const lon = item[5];
                        const lat = item[6];

                        /* DEFINE POPUP TEXT TO BE DISPLAYED*/
                        const popupText = "<p>"+item[0] + " - " + item[1] + "<br/>Lat: " + lat.toFixed(2)+" / Lon: "+lon.toFixed(2)+"<br/>Epoch: "+ts+"</p>";

                        /* ADD ITEM TO THE MAP. CALL getICAO24 FUNCTION BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SAVE THE OUTPUT*/
                        L.circle(L.latLng(
                            parseFloat(item[6]), // lon
                            parseFloat(item[5])  // lat
                        ), damsRadius).addTo(layerGroup).bindPopup(popupText).on('click', getIcao24);

                        document.getElementById('ts').textContent = ts;
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                }               

            }
            /* CALL FUNCTION FIRST TIME*/
            getOpensky();

            /* UPDATE FUNCTION EVERY 10 SECONDS */
            setInterval(getOpensky, 10000);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Every time I click on an aircraft (*`item`*), the popup window opens as expected. However, I would like to keep the selected popup text open even after the refresh has occurred (*`setInterval`* every 10 seconds). This is not happening due to the fact that when I click on the tooltip, the output is only displayed on the console but not store anywhere to be somehow recognized during the next query.

I though that one possible solution is to add a function called *`getIcao24`* which should return the popup text and get the unique *`icao24`* code (*`item[0]`*) from the string and then check when it appears in the next iteration and set the popup box as open. However I have no clue how to get such information out of the function.

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal, i.e. maintain the popup box of a clicked item open even after a refresh has occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many ways to achieve what you want, below is described one of them I usually use.

To have handy some property when you process marker event, you can 'misuse' marker object and just define this property as a new maker property, to which you can give any name as long as it does not collide with standard properties. In the example below it's `_myID`, which gets the value of `item[0]`.

Then when popup is opened (more pertinent `popupopen` event is used), `_myID` property is saved in global variable `idPopup`.

When markers are refreshed next time, `item[0]` values are compared to saved id and upon match popup is opened.

There is also `popupclose` event processing function to clear `idPopup` if popup is closed by user before refresh. Since popup is closed also at the time marker removal/referesh, there is `refreshInProgress` variable to take care of that. `popupFound` variable takes care of the case when marker with the popup is not displayed upon next refresh.

So the code could the look something like this:

```
var idPopup = '';            

function getIcao24(e) {
  idPopup = e.target._myID;
}

function processPopupClose(e) {
  if (!refreshInProgress) {
    idPopup = '';
  }
}

async function getOpensky() {
  var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
  ts = ts.toString();
  const  response = await fetch(opensky_url.replace('TIME',ts));
  const data = await response.json();
  refreshInProgress = true;
  layerGroup.clearLayers();
  popupFound = false;
  for (var key in data.states) {
    const item = data.states[key];
    try { 
      const lon = item[5];
      const lat = item[6];
      const popupText = "<p>"+item[0] + " - " + item[1] + "<br/>Lat: " + lat.toFixed(2)+" / Lon: "+lon.toFixed(2)+"<br/>Epoch: "+ts+"</p>";
      var marker = L.circle(L.latLng(
        parseFloat(item[6]), // lon
        parseFloat(item[5])  // lat
      ), damsRadius).addTo(layerGroup).bindPopup(popupText)
      .on('popupopen', getIcao24)
      .on('popupclose', processPopupClose);
      marker._myID = item[0];
      if (item[0] == idPopup) {
        marker.openPopup();
        popupFound = true;
      }
      document.getElementById('ts').textContent = ts;
    }
    catch (e) {}
  }               
  if (!popupFound) idPopup = '';
  refreshInProgress = false;
}
```

Comment: @TimazlcM Thanks for your answer! It looks it works at the begninning but after one iteration it gets stuck and everything freezes so i have to close the browser. Have you tested it on your PC as well? do you encounter the same issue?

PS: I found a very bad workaround to my problem and it does't get stuck but it is not very good programming practice what I did.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it, not with your GeoJSON, but with some random markers. Since I have ES5 environment, my code was a bit different and I might have made some errors when constructing answer for your ES6 environment. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I noticed an error in the code and corrected it. It should be `item[0]`, not `item[0].id`

Comment: Perfect! Now it is great!! :) Thanks a lot @TomazicM